# yii get data using relations between models

Tags: php, sql, yii, mysqli

I wanna get all list of categories and subcategories which is `enabled=1`

relations in categories:

```
return array(
            'subcategories'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Subcategories', 'id','condition'=>'enabled=1'),
        );
```

relations in subcategories:

```
return array(
            'categories'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Categories', 'category_id', 'condition'=>'enabled=1'),
        );
```

Here is what i wanna to do:

```
$categories = Categories::model()->with('subcategories')->findAll();
    $selectData = array();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $selectData[$category->title] = CHtml::listData($category->subcategories, 'id', 'title');
    }
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('catAndSubcat', null, $selectData);
```

Both tables has column `enabled`. Each category has near 10 subcategories.
`category_id` in subcategories is foreign key of `id` in categories

But im getting error:

```
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'enabled' in where clause is ambiguous. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`title` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`page_id` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`position` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`enabled` AS `t0_c4`, `subcategories`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `subcategories`.`category_id` AS `t1_c1`, `subcategories`.`title` AS `t1_c2`, `subcategories`.`page_id` AS `t1_c3`, `subcategories`.`position` AS `t1_c4`, `subcategories`.`enabled` AS `t1_c5` FROM `t_categories` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `t_subcategories` `subcategories` ON (`subcategories`.`id`=`t`.`id`) WHERE (enabled=1)
```

Help ME!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use table aliases like this:

```
 array(
        'subcategories'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Subcategories', 'id','condition'=>'subcategories.enabled=1'),
    );
 array(
        'categories'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Categories', 'category_id', 'condition'=>'categories.enabled=1'),
    );
```

**Update:**

```
$categories = Categories::model()->with('subcategories')->findAll(array('condition' => 't.enabled=1'));
```

Comment: `SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`title` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`page_id` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`position` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`enabled` AS `t0_c4`, `subcategories`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `subcategories`.`category_id` AS `t1_c1`, `subcategories`.`title` AS `t1_c2`, `subcategories`.`page_id` AS `t1_c3`, `subcategories`.`position` AS `t1_c4`, `subcategories`.`enabled` AS `t1_c5` FROM `t_categories` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `t_subcategories` `subcategories` ON (`subcategories`.`id`=`t`.`id`) WHERE (subcategories.enabled=1)`

Comment: it gets data from tables without taking into account only categories that enabled

Comment: Now you SQL works wothout erros? What do you mean "without taking into account"?

Comment: yes, it is without errors. i mean that it gets from table all categories, but im need to take only categories that has `enabled=1`.It hasnt included this condition in query

Comment: Try this: $categories = Categories::model()->with('subcategories')->findAll(array('condition' => 't.enabled=1'));

Comment: this works fine and it shows what i want! but why not working in relations?

Comment: Your relation works correct. If you want all in one, then try this:
array(
        'categories'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Categories', 'category_id', 'condition'=>'t.enabled=1 AND subcategories.enabled=1',),
    );

Comment: The reason, why I don't reccomend you to filter enabled records in relations, is because if you'll need ALL record you couldn't do this - you will always get records enabled=1...
So better way is to use condition inside findAll() method. Good luck!

Comment: this not working good. in this time it is also not including a condition categories.enabled=1. ive just checked more detailed - this solution also isnt working right Categories::model()->with('subcategories')->findAll(array('condition' => 't.enabled=1'));

Comment: this is sql that i wanna execute through relations `SELECT t_categories.title AS c_title, t_subcategories.* FROM t_categories, t_subcategories WHERE t_categories.enabled=1 AND t_subcategories.enabled=1 AND t_categories.id=t_subcategories.category_id`

Comment: So why not? Categories::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT t_categories.title AS c_title, t_subcategories.* FROM t_categories, t_subcategories WHERE t_categories.enabled=1 AND t_subcategories.enabled=1 AND t_categories.id=t_subcategories.category_id');

Answer (score 0):

You can try.

```
return array(
        'subcategories'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Subcategories', 'id','on'=>'subcategories.enabled=1'),
    );
```

Condition not working in relations i think.

Edit: or you can try.

```
return array(
    'subcategories'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Subcategories','id'),
);
```

In your controler:

```
Categories::model()->with('subcategories')->findAllByAttributes(array('subcategories.enabled'=>1));
```